# Query to rewrite http to https despite slashes?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am migrating my website from http to https. All went well except for the slides made by a plugin called revolution slider.

I checked out the MySQL database and found entries like these:

{"background_type":"image","image":"http: \ / \ / example.com \ / wp-content \ /uploads \ / 2014 \ /03 \ /Banner_1.jpg",

Normally I would use NotePad++ or Phpmyadmin and do a search replace:

```
UPDATE x_posts SET y = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://www.example.com', 'https://www.example.com');
```

However due to the usage of : \ / \ / this is not working as expected. I can't even find the domain in question when I do a global database search.

Is it possible to write a query to fix these slides located in xr_revslider_slides / params ?

ps I had to add spaces to prevent auto-translation to ://

Answer (score 1):

This is a theory, but maybe your data is *stored* with the extra slashes and not just a json retrieval issue?

In this case,

```
UPDATE x_posts SET y = REPLACE (post_content, 'http:\/\/www.example.com', 'https://www.example.com');
```

would do it.

Comment: When I browse the table manually I notice the data is indeed stored with the additional slashes

Answer (score 1):

JSON escapes forward slashes with backslashes.

MySQL expects backslashes in queries to be escaped with backslashes, because otherwise the backslash is interpreted as an escape character.

The literal string `\` in a MySQL query is written as `\\`, thus:

```
UPDATE x_posts 
   SET y = REPLACE (post_content, 'http:\\/\\/www.example.com', 'https:\\/\\/www.example.com');
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html